# Laravel use view while sending email from Gmail API

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying to send emails using Gmail API. It worked fine if I use raw body, but I am unable to figure out how to use Laravel Views as the body when sending the email from Gmail API . Or use Gmail API to send using Laravel Mail 
Here is my code:

```
        $strSubject = 'Test mail using GMail API';
        $strRawMessage = "To: Someone <someone@domain.com>\r\n";
        $strRawMessage .= 'Subject: =?utf-8?B?' . base64_encode($strSubject) . "?=\r\n";
        $strRawMessage .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $strRawMessage .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
        $strRawMessage .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable' . "\r\n\r\n";
        $strRawMessage .= "this is body";
        $service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);

        try{
            $mime = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($strRawMessage), '+/', '-_'), '=');
            $msg = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message($client);

            $msg->setRaw($mime);
            $service->users_messages->send("me", $msg);

        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            \Log::info($e->getMessage());

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, you should be able to generate a "mailable" class with php artisan make:mail command. This way, you will be able to use laravel mail api, meaning be able to use view and stuff.

Second thing, laravel should be able to send the mail for you, in order to be able to do it it requires some configuration.

What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I am using 5.5 , can you point me to the documentation or tutorial for that.

Comment: Let me know if you can't figure out... here is the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail

Comment: Here is a tutorial of how to achieve it with Laravel 5.4. https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/26